# Eslint rule for array of objects

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there eslint rule that requires developers to declare array in more concise way, like:

BAD:

```
const array = [
  {
    name: 'x'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'y'
  }
];
```

GOOD:

```
const array = [{
  name: 'x'
}, {
  name: 'y'
}];
```

Comment: no. Anyway, why would you want to do that?

Comment: I think it is completely opinion based, what you call bad, can be good for someone else, it don't change anything in the structure, it just changes the readability

Comment: Most eslint rules are opinion based and developers may turn them on/off. In case of team I work in, we wanted to unify style for that case in our codebase, and we subjectively chose "GOOD" way for us. I placed question here because eslint rule may help us to achieve consistency, and I couldn't find good one.

Comment: Hi @lusarz could you find a solution?, I'm looking for the same configuration.

Comment: Hi @Jacobi - unfortunately not yet